# MopaBootstrapBundle adding navbar inverse option

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, bundle, symfony-2.1

I am using MopaBootstrapBundle in my Symfony project.

My current configuration in config.yml is:

```
mopa_bootstrap:
    navbar: ~
```

How do I add inverse property to make the navbar dark using config.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should create a service to do it.

//services.yml

```
services:
    mopa_bootstrap.example.navbar:
        class: %mopa_bootstrap.navbar.generic%
        arguments:
            # first argument: a named array of menues:
            - { leftmenu: @mopa_bootstrap.examplemenu=, rightmenu: @mopa_bootstrap.exampledropdown= }
            # second argument: a named array of FormType Classes
            - { searchform: Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapSandboxBundle\Form\Type\ExampleSearchFormType }
            # third argument: a named array of options
            - { title: "BootstrapSandbox", titleRoute: "mopa_bootstrap_welcome", fixedTop: true, isFluid: false, inverse: true }
        tags:
            # The alias is used to retrieve the navbar in templates
            - { name: mopa_bootstrap.navbar, alias: sandboxFrontendNavbar }
```

You can see inverse option in third argument.

FYI:
https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapSandboxBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/examples/example_navbar.yml

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mopa_bootstrap:
    navbar:
        inverse: true
```

See: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Navbar/navbar.html.twig

Comment: I think, you cannot pass inverse option via configuration as there is no such option in configuration!